# Admin On Rest: Admin component should re-render when a correct login occurs

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

So I working with users with specific roles and permissions. Two of this roles have is own Dashboard but the rest doesn't. So basically i'm doing something like this on my `App.js`:

```
const AdminProps = {
  title: <Header />,
  theme: getMuiTheme(SnapbackTheme),
  locale: 'en',
  restClient,
  authClient: AuthClient,
  loginPage: LoginPage
}

let AppLayout = <Admin {...AdminProps } />

if (userRoleIs(USER_ROLE_1)) {
  AppLayout = (
    <Admin {...AdminProps } dashboard={CustomDashboardForThisRole}>
      <Resource name="resource1" list={resource1List} />
    </Admin>
  )
}

if (userRoleIs(USER_ROLE_2)) {
  AppLayout = (
    <Admin {...AdminProps }>
      <Resource name="resource1" list={resource1List} />
    </Admin>
  )
}

return AppLayout
```

As you can see, depending of the user that is logged in I can choose which props `Admin` should have. This is working, kind of, the problem with this is that when you log in with a user and find out which role has I don't have a proper way to update the `Admin` props and re-render it.

That causes a empty content screen when logging in with users that have custom dashboard until I refresh the page and Admin render correctly with the correct dashboard for the user.

My ugly workaround at the moment: a `window.location.reload()` when the login was successful but you can see the empty content screen for a second and it looks awful.

My question is: Is there a proper way to re-render the `Admin` component from the authClient?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to use [`aor-permissions`](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-permissions), which introduces the `<WithPermission>` and `<SwitchPermissions>` components. You can use the latter to wrap the parts that need rerendering in your Dashboard:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SwitchPermissions, Permission } from 'aor-permissions';
import authClient from './authClient';

const Dashboard = () => (
    <SwitchPermissions authClient={authClient}>
        <Permission value={USER_ROLE_1}>
            <CustomDashboardForThisRole />
        </Permission>
    </SwitchPermissions>
);
```

Then, import this `Dashboard` component in your `Admin` directly.

Comment: What if we just want to change the "Title" content based on the login?
Please check the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537944/how-to-dynamically-change-the-title-of-app-based-on-login-info-i-e-after

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your code is not shown, so it is kind of difficult to prescribe specific solution.But let us assume that you are using react + redux to store state (if you are not using redux, most of the comments would still hold).

Somewhere in your state you will have a key adminInfo, with initial value of false. On your server, there will be route you can post username and password, and provided they are ok you would get content for admin props or something like that.

Your compoments will get data from the state, so initially you would display components acoording to adminInfo beeing false. When user enters credentials, you would issue ajax call to the server. When server responds with admin props, you would update your state under adminInfo to have data received from the server. When you update state, your components would rerender, now finding complete admin info and display accordingly

Comment: Thanks man, yeah but that is what the admin-on-rest framework should do, i'm just another user of their framework and [they said is not their problem and I should post it here](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/790#event-1136592651), wtf then :/

Comment: I see, hope someone with admin on rest experience will be able to help you out.

Comment: We did not say it's not our prb, just that we only handle bugs in github. Can you show the code of the component containing the code you posted ? I suppose it's part of the render method of something ?

Comment: If it's not part of the render method of a component, then it's impossible to re-render it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement where the Menu/Resources under the `Admin` Element should be rendered based on who is logged in. The approach I am taking is to render `WrapperApp` that renders the `Admin` app as a child. The `WrapperApp` connects to it's own thin Redux Store/Actions/Router layer that takes care of the Login/Logout behavior of my App. Based on who is logged in, the Wrapper decides the set of Resources to be passed on to the `Admin` child element. Now, whenever the auth token/cookie expires, the `Admin authClient` notices the error and invokes the WrapperApp's `logout` action. This will redirect my `WrapperApp` to it's login page and the cycle continues further based on who is logged in. The `Admin` child element's authClient is made aware of the wrapper app's actions. Like below:

```
<Admin ... authClient={authClient.withActions(wrapperActions)} .. />
```

`withActions` curries my wrapper app actions into the AuthClient.