# How to dynamically change the "title" of "app", based on login info (i.e. after login succeeds or logout)?

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

I have this code, please see the `title` prop:

```
const App = () => (
  <Admin
    theme={theme}
    customRoutes={customRoutes}
    menu={Menu}
    dataProvider={loopbackRestClient(window.apiUrl)}
    authProvider={authClient()}
    dashboard={Dashboard}
    locale="en"
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
    title={`Dashboard - ${window.accountData ? window.accountData.accommodation.name : ''}`}
  >
  // more code here...
```

This tries to change the rendered `title` when login succeeds and therefore we get different `accommodation.name` value from there.

I was expecting that the component may re-render with this event, since login affects the REDUX state, so the `window` variable (which changed after login) should render a different title.

It did not work.

How may we do it the proper way (react-redux way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a custom and connected `Title` component and pass it as the `title` prop.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1072ry6rl7

Note that my custom `Title` component has to support a `className` prop. This is a `material-ui` requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but I tested this and the title did not appear (even with a plain, non-connected React Node). Please check here:

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1743#issuecomment-381507884

Comment: Edited my answer with an example

Comment: @Glidas, how would we dispatch the action of updating the "title" in the store from within the `AuthClient` though? See here the related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928538/react-admin-how-can-we-dispatch-a-store-action-from-within-the-authprovider-c

Comment: Answered in the authClient question :)

Answer (score 1):

You should save that accountData you currently have on the window object in the Redux store in its own Reducer. And when your LOGIN Action is fired I would update that accountData with the new data.

Comment: Thanks, you mean that we should connect <Admin> to Redux? Because now it does not seem to be connected. How would that work?

Comment: Inside of `<Admin />` you just use the `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` function.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean "inside of <Admin />?" Since "title" is a prop of Admin, how can we use the connect function there? Thx!

Comment: Sorry, I mean you don't have to do anything inside the Admin component. I assume your App component is already connected to the store. Then there you would just use `mapStateToProps` to pass the `accountData` as props to the App component.

Comment: It does not seem to be easy to connect the "App" (it is the very first compoenent rendered). I get the following error: "×
Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)"."

Comment: This means that you need `import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
const store = createStore(RootReducer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,`

Comment: Thanks Theo, good suggestions. I believe that it is simpler to do what Glidas recommends, just connect the title to the store. Thanks again!