# React-Admin: How can we dispatch a store action from within the `authProvider` code?

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

In the async fetch of the `AUTH_LOGIN` *we want to dispatch an action* after we fetch data from additional endpoints (apart from the login endpoint, for example we call another endpoint to bring data for the account, etc.).

We have all in place (action, reducer, used the combineReducers, etc.), but we are not sure how we can "connect" the `authClient` function in the `authClient.js` file, as this is not a `component` in order to use the `connect` function.

How could we `dispatch` an action then?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [authentication side effect](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/sideEffect/auth.js#L35), the data returned by your `authClient` will be set as the payload of the `USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS` action which will be dispatched automatically when the `authClient` resolve.

To apply any logic to the authentication payloa and eventually dispatch some custom actions, you'll have to create a [custom saga](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customsagas) which will react to `USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS` actions.

We should definitely add an example in the documentation

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, if you could add an examplein the documentation that would be great because the 'saga' concepts are new to many devs.

Comment: @Glidas, I succeeded based on your recommendations! Only one "culprit" is that I also have to do the same FETCH for "CHECK_USER", so that the app will fetch the necessary (extra) data even when a BROWSER REFRESH occurs. I have a "window.extraDataFetched" flag that I got the data, but while this does work it does fetch 3 times in the beginning. Any ideas how to disallow this?

Comment: Actually, I used `takeLatest(USER_CHECK, fetchExtraLoginData)` instead and seems to be working, except that it fetches 2 times, not just 1.