# react-admin login saga not running

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, react-admin

I need to dispatch an action from a custom reducer, every time the user authenticates in react-admin. Since I don't have access to the redux store inside my auth provider, I have to create a saga, according to this post [React-Admin: How can we dispatch a store action from within the `authProvider` code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928538/react-admin-how-can-we-dispatch-a-store-action-from-within-the-authprovider-c)

This is my code:

```
// index.ts
function App() {
  return (
    <Admin
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
      authProvider={authProvider}
      customReducers={{ myReducer }}
      customSagas={[authSaga]}
    >
      [...]
    </Admin>
  );
}

// authSaga.ts
import { put, take } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS } from "ra-core";
import { showNotification } from "react-admin";

const authSaga = function* () {
  while (true) {
    console.log("SAGA RUNNING");
    yield take(USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS);

    // This never runs
    console.log("USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS RUNNING");
    yield put(showNotification("TEST"));
  }
};

export default authSaga;
```

I can see in the console the message "SAGA RUNNING", but when the user authenticates, the second log doesn't run. I tried with the USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS constant, and also with "USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS". I also tried using takeEvery, but nothing works. "authSaga" is pointing to my saga, not the one included in react-admin. This is the first time I use redux-saga, so I'm probably missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that action USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS was disabled a long time ago, it also does not occur in my application, try using REGISTER_RESOURCE / UNREGISTER_RESOURCE instead.
Note that action REGISTER_RESOURCE / UNREGISTER_RESOURCE will occur for each of your resources.

Comment: I can't use those actions. The data I need to save in my redux store is returned by the server on login (when react-admin executes authProvider.login()), so ideally I need to dispatch my action there. I also save this data in local storage, so technically I should be able to read it somewhere else, right after authenticating the user, but this sounds like an unnecessary extra step. There should be a better way to dispatch an action from the authProvider.